# MSBuild Error after upgrading TeamFoundation dlls to 2017

Tags: dll, tfs, msbuild

So, we were using 2013 TFS dlls in our projects (namely TeamFoundation.Client, TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, and TeamFoundation.Common). I recently upgraded the project to use 2017 versions of the above mentioned dlls (We have VS2017). I am getting them from the below folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

After upgrading, when I build my solution, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets(56,5): warning : Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

I am not familiar with MSBuild so not sure how to proceed.

The error takes me to the following line in the MSBuild code:

```
GetDependsOnNETStandard Condition="'$(_RunGetDependsOnNETStandard)' == 'true'"
                         References="@(_CandidateNETStandardReferences)">
  <Output TaskParameter="DependsOnNETStandard" PropertyName="DependsOnNETStandard" />
</GetDependsOnNETStandard>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build through Visual Studio locally or through TFS server build?

Comment: I am building locally. But I found my issue. After I installed the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient  nuget package and re-built, the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

There is an outstanding issue with Visual Studio 2017 and DependsOnNETStandard that should hopefully be resolved in 15.8

I just encountered the same problem today when upgrading a project that was originally created VS 2015 and upgraded to VS 2017.

It looks like the upgrade of the projects misses a few elements in the XML that it needs.

If you edit the csproj files of the effected projects and add

```
<DependsOnNETStandard>false</DependsOnNETStandard>
```

to the top PropertyGroup like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <DependsOnNETStandard>false</DependsOnNETStandard>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It should resolve the issue.  It did for me.

Details of the issue and discussion around it can be found at:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1544

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Would be even better if you could include a link to the outstanding issue (that will be hopefully fixed in 15.8)

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the link to the issue on github repository

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log info, seems you are trying to build locally through Visual Studio or MsBuild command not TFS build.

Suggest you to use the latest version of dlls, [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.134.0-preview) and also upgrade your Visual Studio 2017 to latest version. For `The system cannot find the path specified.` issue try to

- Clean All Projects.
- Unload All Projects
- Reload All Projects.
- ReBuild Solution

Another way is :

- Close the solution
- Delete bin folder
- Delete all obj folders
- Open solution and build

If all of above still not work, suggest you add a more detail log and sample code for troubleshooting.